# Hibernate ManyToMany and Transactional annotation

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, many-to-many, transactional

I try to test my @Repository layer using jUnit and integration testing. In my entity classes I use @ManyToMany bidirectional annotation. My test class I have annotated with @Transactional. When I executing persist method on the parent side of relationship the User object and Role are inserted to databse but there is no relations in join table. When I move @Transactional annotation to @Repository class everything works ok. Maybe someone can exaplain me what is the reason why it is no working when @Transactional annotation is on test class?

User entity:

```
@Table(name = "users")
@Entity
public class User extends BaseEntity  {

    ...

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER,cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(
        name = "users_roles", 
        joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "user_id") }, 
        inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "role_id") }
    )
    private Set<Role> roles;

    .. getters and setters 

    public void addRole(Role role) {
        this.getRoles().add(role);
        role.getUsers().add(this);
    }

    public Set<Role> getRoles() {
        if (this.roles == null) {
            this.roles = new HashSet<>();
        }
        return this.roles;
    }

    public void setRoles(Set<Role> roles) {
        this.roles = roles;
    }
}
```

Role entity

```
@Table(name = "roles")
@Entity
public class Role extends BaseEntity {

    public enum UserRole {
        ADMIN, USER
    }

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name="role")
    private UserRole role;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "roles", fetch = FetchType.EAGER,cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<User> users;

    ... getters and setters
}
```

Test class:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {MysqlPersistanceConfig.class})
@FixMethodOrder(MethodSorters.NAME_ASCENDING)
@Transactional
public class UserRepositoryIT {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Test
    public void stage10_saveOneUserAndCheckIfWasSavedTest() {
        User user = new User();
        user.setName("admin");
        user.setPassword("root");

        Role role1 = new Role(UserRole.USER);
        Role role2 = new Role(UserRole.ADMIN);

        user.addRole(role1);
        user.addRole(role2);

        Assert.assertTrue(role1.getUsers().size() == 1);
        Assert.assertTrue(role2.getUsers().size() == 1);
        Assert.assertTrue(user.getRoles().size() == 2);

        userRepository.save(user);

        Assert.assertEquals(user, userRepository.find(1));
        Assert.assertEquals(user, userRepository.findByName("admin"));
        Assert.assertEquals(2, userRepository.findByName("admin").getRoles().size());
    }
}
```

DAO layer:

```
@Repository
//@Transactional
public class UserRepositoryImpl implements UserRepository {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager manager;

    @Override
    public void save(User user) {
        if(user.isNew()) {
            manager.persist(user);
        } else {
            manager.merge(user);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public User find(int id) {
        return manager.find(User.class, id);
    }

    @Override
    public User findByName(String name) {
        String queryString = "SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.name = :name";
        Query query = manager.createQuery(queryString);

        query.setParameter("name", name);

        return (User) query.getSingleResult();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring's JUnit is rolling back the transaction spanning the test method by default. If you want to check it use `EntityManager manager` in the test and call `manager.flush()` or add `@Rollback(false)` to test method.

Comment: So if it is rolling back the transaction why the user and role are inserted and still in database after transaction ends? There is also no log from hibernate with inserting data to users_roles table.

Comment: Can you see user and role in the database after test finishes and only `users_roles` is empty e.g. by using an external SQL browser?

Comment: Yes, I am using MySQL Workbench to browse data.

Comment: Ok, @Rollback(false) make things work. I was confused that there are role and user existsing in databse after the transatcion ends. Now, there is also log from hiberante at the end of transaction. Thanks!

Comment: @lukassko you do however want this rollback to happen after test to ensure that tests are isolated. It's sane, user created for one test might not be required for test 2.

Comment: I am aware of that. Just for the beginnig I wanted to see if my mappings works and everything in persistance layer is ok.